# How to make an if statement only happen a percentage of the time?

Tags: c#

I've got to write an oven simulator in C sharp, and I want to make it so that an if statement that changes the hob from on to off, only happens 70% of the time, so emulate the spark not igniting the gas as happens on a real oven.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button1.Text == "OFF")
        {
            button1.Text = "ON";
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Ring_Burner_On;
        }
        else if (button1.Text == "ON")
        {
            button1.Text = "OFF";
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Ring_Burner_Off;
        {
```

That's what I have so far, I've never coded before so really at a loss where to go from here.

Comment: Check out the `Random` class so you can generate a value between 0 and 1 and if it's under 0.7 then ignite, but if it's over don't.

Comment: Create a random number from 1 to 100.  If number is above 70 do one thing otherwise do something else.

Comment: You could generate a random number between 1 and 10 and if the number is lower then 8 then u call your function so you have a 70% chanche to trigger the function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try (pseudo)random values

```
// Easiest, but not thread safe
private static Random s_Random = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.Text == "OFF")
    {
        button1.Text = "ON";
        pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Ring_Burner_On;
    }
    else if (button1.Text == "ON")
    {
        if (s_Random.NextDouble() <= 0.7) // 70% per cent of success
        {
            button1.Text = "OFF";
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Ring_Burner_Off;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use math, random method.

You could do something like:

```
var min = 1;
var max = 100;
Random random = new Random();  
if( random.Next(min, max) > 70) 
{
   //turn on. 
}
else
{
   //turn off.
}
```

Comment: no need to go up to 100 to get the 70%. Just set max = 10 and condition >7

Comment: You should better not create a new Random object every time, but only once and store it in a class field.

Comment: This is obviously just a pseudo code example :) I am expecting the OP, to build his objects, the proper way himself.

Comment: @KlausGütter: or, even better, a **static readonly** class field with an initializer.

Comment: @Synapsis You don't need a max at all.  `NextDouble` will be between 0 and 1 and you just compare to 0.7.  Note that when you call `Next` it actually generates a random number between 0 and 1 and then multiplies and truncates to make it an `int` in the given range.

Comment: As the OP asked for "70%" of the time, I thought it better to define numbers, so it related mostly to a percentage. 
reducing a statement to make it less readable, is not always an upgrade of code. 

In this example, the resulting type would likely be an int, not a decimal or long. 
So you would also have to specify that your solution have a type specification as a requirement. 

On top of that, this is pseudo.This snippet, does not in-fact run. Talking about optimizing code, that doesn't run, is taking the focus off the fact, that the idea, is clear enough. Anything else is just guesses